# speculative deductive reasoning

Tags: philosophy-of-science, epistemology, scientific-method, deduction, reason

Is hypothetico-deductive reasoning https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetico-deductive_model and speculative deductive reasoning same ?
(speculative deductive reasoning- WE arrive at the explanans propositions through speculation (guessing, imagining, etc.);
explain the explanandum by showing that they are the predictions (the logical
consequences) of the explanans propositions through deductive reasoning; and
justify the explanans propositions by showing that they yield the best available
explanations.
As this involves both speculation and deduction, this mode of reasoning is called Speculative
Deductive Reasoning.)

Comment: No it is not the same thing. Science uses INDUCTIVE REASONING. Deductive reasoning has a definition already.  We need to be aware there can be reasoning that is mixed with other types of reasoning. Deductive reasoning is not an all or nothing type of classification. All subjects can have SOME deductive reasoning involved.  Pure deductive reasoning is distinct from those subjects that use partial or SOME portion of deductive reasoning. Standard form categorical syllogisms are pure deductive reasoning. I only need ideas without experience to solve problems. Deductive reasoning is absolute too

Comment: What is "speculative deductive reasoning", do you have a reference for that?

Comment: There is no obvious meaning to the term "speculative deductive reasoning". You are going to have to define it or give a citation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_reason ?

Comment: I'd add the link above, if that's what you mean.